# How to save dataframe value in excel/csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, outlook, win32com

i am trying to save outlook email body content to dataframe then to csv/excel, we usually get prices from vendor for different indices in tabular format, i tried using Body_content = message.HTMLBody but didnt work as intented.

Thus i am ok with using Body_content = message.Body and print (df.To_string()). Now the next step is to store those values in excel sheet even if its open by an anlyst in below format.

we keep getting index prices  from different vendors, if this one works perfectly, i will follow the same method for others as well.

**Output**

[image]

**This is how it ends up getting a single column dataframe**

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client
import re
import os
import pandas

import datetime
from datetime import date

EMAIL_ACCOUNT = 'lakshmi@NY.com'
EMAIL_SUBJ_SEARCH_STRING = 'MSBPSCSP Index Price'
EMAIL_CONTNT = {'Ticker': [], 'TickerLevel': [], 'DATE': []}

out_app = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
out_namespace = out_app.GetNamespace("MAPI")
#lastWeekDateTime = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days=1)
#lastWeekDateTime = lastWeekDateTime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')


root_folder = out_namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)

out_iter_folder = root_folder.Folders['Email_Snapper']

#char_length_of_search_substring = len(EMAIL_SUBJ_SEARCH_STRING)



item_count = out_iter_folder.Items.Count

Flag = False
cnt = 1
if item_count > 0:
    for i in range(item_count, 0, -1):

        message = out_iter_folder.Items[i]
        if EMAIL_SUBJ_SEARCH_STRING in message.Subject:
            #message = message.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + lastWeekDateTime + "'")

            Body_content = message.Body
Body_content = Body_content[:Body_content.find("Disclaimer")].strip()
df = pd.DataFrame([Body_content])
print(df.to_string())
```

The final objective is to insert those prices in oracle database either through saving them in excel first or if possible directly from the dataframe (that's even better)

Comment: "i tried using Body_content = message.HTMLBody but didnt work as intented" ... did the html have table tags (eg <tr><td>) in it? Is the email arriving as plain text or HTML?

Answer (score 2):

You can export the `dataFrame` to excel

`df.to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False)`

or CSV -

`df.to_excel("output.csv", index=False)`

Comment: thanks ahmed, is it possible to save only specific values from dataframe like MSBPSCSSP in column A, date in column B and price in column C

Comment: yes, `df.date` will return only date column and `df[['date']].to_excel()` will save only that column values

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model supports three main ways of customizing or getting the message body:

1. The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-body-property-outlook) property returns or sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. The [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-htmlbody-property-outlook) property of the `MailItem` class returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the `HTMLBody` property will always update the `Body` property immediately. For example:

```
     Sub CreateHTMLMail() 
       'Creates a new e-mail item and modifies its properties. 
       Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem 
       'Create e-mail item 
       Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
       With objMail 
        'Set body format to HTML 
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 
        .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message <a href="http://google.com">text</a> here. </BODY></HTML>" 
        .Display 
       End With 
     End Sub
```

3. The Word object model can be used for dealing with message bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information. So, you can get the required information using the Word object model.

It is up to you which way is to choose. But I suppose the Word object model can help you with extracting the required information.

Comment: isnt it more related to vba ?

Comment: can anyone pls help me suggesting a change in code ?

Comment: @RahulVaidya The VBA is directly portable to Python, using win32com. The objects, methods and properties are the same, as they come from the same object model.